# If $u$ is transcendental over a field $F$, can it be the case that $F(u) = F(u^2)$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

As seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811387/prove-that-if-fuf-is-odd-then-fu-fu2), if $u$ is algebraic over a field $F$ and $[F(u):F]$ is odd then then $F(u) = F(u^2)$.  If instead $u$ is transcendental over $F$, can it be the case that $F(u) = F(u^2)$?

Comment: Hint: can you have $u\in F(u^2)$? What would that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F(u) = F(u^2)$, then you can write $u$ as a rational function in $u^2$. Say $u =  f(u^2)/g(u^2)$ for some polynomials $f$ and $g$. But then $ug(u^2) - f(u^2) = 0$, implying that $u$ is algebraic over $F$.